# WordPress WP_Query custom order_by post_type functionality

Tags: wp-query, order

I'm on WordPress 6.2.2. I’ve got a query which retrieves content for a given meta value.

```
$query_posts_for_board_game = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => ['reviews','articles', 'topics'],
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'meta_query' => array(
           // left empty for brevity
        ),
    )
);
```

Which returns the following list:

```
Expanding Everdell: A Ranking <-- article
Everdell Digital Game Review <-- review
Board Games with Animeeples <-- topic
Everdell Newleaf & Mistwood Game Video Review <-- review
Everdell Game Review <-- review
```

[image: Example of current sort order]

I’d like to force reviews to be first in the list, then articles, then topics. I know that I can adjust the order by adding this to my query:

```
'orderby' => 'post_type',
'order' => 'desc',
```

But that puts topics before reviews in reverse alphabetical order. Does PHP / WordPress allow us to use a dynamic orderby statement? Here's a link to the page in question if you want to see more examples: `https://www.meeplemountain.com/trending-board-games/`

**NOTE:** I ended up "solving" this by splitting my query into two parts. I'm running a query to get just reviews, another query to articles and topics (in ascending order so that articles come first), then array_merge-ing the two queries together. Since I'm storing the combined array in a transient, the results are just as fast once it gets cached.

I'm asking here because I still think there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, in your current approach, WordPress does not natively support ordering by specific post types in `WP_Query`. However, you can still achieve what you're looking for through a custom SQL clause. By using the `posts_clauses` filter, you can modify the SQL query before it's executed.

Please note that using custom SQL queries should be done cautiously, as it can lead to unexpected results or vulnerabilities if not handled properly.

Here's a sample of how you could modify your query using this approach:

```
function custom_posts_orderby($orderby_statement) {
    $orderby_statement = "FIELD(post_type, 'reviews', 'articles', 'topics') ASC";
    return $orderby_statement;
}

add_filter('posts_orderby', 'custom_posts_orderby');

$query_posts_for_board_game = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => ['reviews','articles', 'topics'],
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'meta_query' => array(
            // put your additional meta query here
        ),
    )
);

remove_filter('posts_orderby', 'custom_posts_orderby');
```

In this code, we use the `posts_orderby` filter to change the SQL '**ORDER BY**' clause so that it orders by the `post_type` field according to the order we specify in the **FIELD** function ('reviews' first, then 'articles', then 'topics'). After the query is executed, we immediately remove the filter with `remove_filter` to ensure that it doesn't affect other queries.

Make sure you thoroughly test the code, I didn't test it on my end.

Comment: This looks like it was written by ChatGPT.

Comment: @Shivam English is my third language, I utilize a grammar correction tool to enhance my responses for better understanding.

Comment: While I haven't tried this exact code, I did try something similar and couldn't get it working. I also couldn't find documentation in WordPress or anywhere else on the FIELD function in your example. What does it do, and can you provide a link?